# Passing params in ionic sidemenu

Tags: ionic-framework, parameters, pass-data, navparams

When a user logins the ionic app, how do I pass the user ID to the pages listed in side menu.. Is there a possibility to send data through navParams?

Comment: you can maintain the localstorage variable  and based on that localStorage variable you can change the page or page link in your app component.

Comment: And Yeah NavParams and NavController has this feature you can send data while you push the page. and read those data through navParams

Answer (score 2):

You have to store user ID in ionic storage when the user is login like this,

First, add [Ionic storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) in your app,

Then, use ionic storage in login component like this,

```
// set user ID
storage.set('userID', 'Your_user_ID');
```

Now, get the user ID in whichever component you want like this,

```
// get user ID
storage.get('userID').then((val) => {
  console.log('user ID', val);
});
```

Thank you.